# How to copy a button with shadow effect from PSD to PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selection

I got a web site design in PSD file from a web-designer. All element s there snap to guides, which is handy when I make a selection to copy an element of design to a PNG file: guides make my selection precise.

One button there has two states: normal and hover. Both states contains of several layers. So I am trying to copy both states as PNG files in order to make a nice button in html.

The problem is that both states have shadow effects, which go beyond the layers' edges, i.e. when I try to select a button my selection (snapped to guides) does not include an outer part of the shadow.

How do I make a precise selection of the button state in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I use to extract elements from PSDs:

1) Make sure only the layers of the button are visible. Hide all the others.
2) Make sure there is no background or any other unwanted color or semi-transparent pixels "hiding" or this will not work.
3) From the menu, select **"Image" -> "Trim"**, and select all the checkboxes. Click "OK".

You should now have only the desired layers visible, including the effects (if they were visible).
Now you can use "Save for web & devices" to save the file.